# Parsing nested JSON data within keys

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse nested JSON data. I'm trying to get the 'DisplayValue' for each key, my code is

```
json_obj = r.json()
for result in json_obj["Result"]:
    for employeeid in result["EmployeeId"]:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee_detail (EmployeeId) VALUES (%s)",
                       (result["DisplayValue"]))
```

However I get the response

> KeyError 'DisplayValue'

JSON output

```
{
"IsError": "false",
"Status": 0,
"Message": "string",
"Result": [
    {
        "EmployeeId": {
        "DisplayValue": "PW180",
        "FieldHistory": []
        },

        "Title": {
        "DisplayValue": "Mr.",
        "FieldHistory": []
        },
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need the second for loop just use `result['EmployeeId']['DisplayValue']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested dictionary.

Use:

```
json_obj = r.json()
for result in json_obj["Result"]:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee_detail (EmployeeId) VALUES (%s)",
                       (result['EmployeeId']["DisplayValue"],))
```